# Unable to use a customised theme in MUI - Material Design Framework for my Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, material-design

I went to the customisation page of MUI - Material Design CSS Framework and there they said to a) Create a sass file b) Use the variables and import the files c) Compile the sass file.

I had installed mui in my project through bower. But my customised theme isn't working.

Do I have to download or do anything else?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.